# Incomplete video when using ffmpeg to weave WAV and PNG

Tags: r, ffmpeg, png, mp4, wav

I am trying to "weave" PNG image files with a WAV file. Here is the `ffmpeg` command that I used:

```
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_6/bin/ffmpeg' -y -f concat -safe 0 -i '/private/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T/Rtmp8gnKo7/ari_input_NQIg95oycVnb.txt' -i '/private/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T/Rtmp8gnKo7/ari_audio_ngNm5vr2vFta.wav' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2    -shortest -fps_mode auto -pix_fmt yuv420p  -vf fps=5,\"scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2\"   -strict experimental -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -threads 2 '/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T//Rtmp8gnKo7/file46521ffd4ef8.mp4'
```

While `ffmpeg` is doing its thing, I get this long message:

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, concat, from '/private/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T/Rtmp8gnKo7/ari_input_NQIg95oycVnb.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:37.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 6000x3375 [SAR 23622:23622 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Input #1, wav, from '/private/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T/Rtmp8gnKo7/ari_audio_ngNm5vr2vFta.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:37.00, bitrate: 352 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s16, 352 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] using SAR=3374/3375
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=2 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/folders/bb/m2b0ry595ys7bfs1r397lnf40000gp/T//Rtmp8gnKo7/file46521ffd4ef8.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 6000x3374 [SAR 3374:3375 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 5 fps, 10240 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 aac
frame=  150 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=     658kB time=00:00:30.00 bitrate= 179.7kbits/s speed=2.21x    
video:286kB audio:364kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.219465%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] frame I:2     Avg QP: 2.27  size: 77096
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] frame P:38    Avg QP:12.33  size:  1831
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] frame B:110   Avg QP:12.66  size:   622
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] consecutive B-frames:  2.0%  0.0%  2.0% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] mb I  I16..4: 95.0%  2.4%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:60.3% L1:39.7% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] 8x8 transform intra:3.0% inter:3.7%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 1.7% 0.4% 0.4% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 99%  1%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 79%  2% 19%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 47% 16% 24%  2%  2%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 99%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] ref P L0: 87.6%  1.9%  9.4%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] ref B L0: 56.8% 41.9%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] ref B L1: 97.9%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x13c9084e0] kb/s:77.92
[aac @ 0x13c9098c0] Qavg: 60691.250
```

The output, a mp4 video file, isn't what I expected. I expected 6 PNG images embedded with my combined WAV file, but the video only shows 5 PNG images and a shortened WAV file.

Here is the content of the `txt` file, `ari_input_NQIg95oycVnb.txt`:

```
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide1.png'
duration 6
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide2.png'
duration 6
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide3.png'
duration 6
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide4.png'
duration 6
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide5.png'
duration 6
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide6.png'
duration 7
```

I wanted to attach my WAV file and PNG files to make this question more reproducible, but couldn't so I'll redirect you to my GitHub issue, which contains 6 separate WAV files and 6 PNG files.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `duration` directive in the concat demuxer is not intuitively designed

It actually offsets the start time of the *next* entry relative to the current entry. So the last entry here will be shown for one frame length. When `duration` is meant to be applied to the last image, duplicate that last entry i.e.

```
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide6.png'
duration 7
file '/Users/howardbaek/Documents/sandbox/loqui/png_files/slide6.png'
```

The audio is shortened because you have `-shortest` declared and video terminates at 30s.

Comment: This answer is awesome! Do you mind explaining what why we duplicate that last entry again?